# How can we export Elastic search metrics from AWS cloud watch exporter to prometheus

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, slack, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-alerts

I've been working on exporting AWS Elasticsearch (AWS/ES) metrics to Prometheus using the Prometheus CloudWatch Exporter, following the setup described in the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/prometheus/cloudwatch_exporter).

I've successfully managed to export various AWS metrics using a configuration similar to the following for AWS Elastic Load Balancers (AWS/ELB):

```yaml
region: eu-west-1
metrics:
 - aws_namespace: AWS/ELB
   aws_metric_name: RequestCount
   aws_dimensions: [AvailabilityZone, LoadBalancerName]
   aws_dimension_select:
     LoadBalancerName: [myLB]
   aws_statistics: [Sum]
```

Unfortunately, this setup is not providing the Elasticsearch metrics.

My ultimate goal is to establish alerts in Prometheus so that I can receive notifications when these alerts trigger. Currently, I receive emails from AWS CloudWatch, but I'm exploring alternatives for receiving alerts, such as phone calls.

Is there any way to configure phone call alerts directly from AWS CloudWatch without using Prometheus, or is the recommended approach to export metrics to Prometheus, define alerting rules, and configure phone call alerts in Grafana based on those rules?

Need help here.

However, I'm encountering issues when trying to export metrics for AWS Elasticsearch. Here's the configuration I've attempted:

```yaml
- aws_namespace: AWS/ES
  aws_metric_name: JVMMemoryPressure
  aws_statistics: [Average]
  aws_dimensions: [DomainName, ClientId]
  aws_dimension_select:
    DomainName: [dexter]
    ClientId: [185152735195]
    Region: [Global]
  list_metrics_cache_ttl: 86400
  delay_seconds: 10
  range_seconds: 300
```